# Proof $x\in R^\times \wedge b\in R^\times \Rightarrow ab\in R^\times$

Tags: algebraic-groups

> Let $R$ be a communitative ring. Prove $a\in R^\times \wedge b\in R^\times >\Rightarrow ab\in R^\times$ with $R^\times := \{x\in R\ |\ x\ \text{ >invertible}\}.$

Do you have any ideas and tips on how I could prove this? 
I know that this isn't really difficult but as so often in
proofs concerning algebraic groups you need the right beginning
and I can't get it...

Thanks!

Comment: What do you know about $a$?

Comment: sorry, misspelling. Edited it

Comment: Consider the element $a^{-1}b^{-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Here's a beginning: “Suppose that $a,b \in R^\times$.”

Here's the end: “Therefore, $ab \in R^\times$.

The middle is up to you.  For inspiration, you might try examples with $R=\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$.  What is the inverse of a product of numbers?  Is it expressible in terms of the inverses of the factors?

Comment: Do you mean $(ab)^{-1}=a^{-1} \cdot {b^-1}$ and therefore $a$ and $b$ has to be in $R^\times$ because of the definition of  a ring?

Comment: The inverse elements of $a,b$ exists by assumption!

Comment: @kjwemke13: By your definition, $R^\times$ is the set of *invertible* elements of $R$.  So you have to show that $ab$ is invertible.

Answer (score 0):

With

$a, b \in R^\times, \tag 1$

we have

$c, d \in R^\times \tag 2$

with

$ac = bd = 1_R, \tag 3$

where $1_R$ is the multiplicative identity of $R$; then

$(ab)(cd) = a(bc)d = a(cb)d = (ac)(bd) = 1_R 1_R = 1_R, \tag 4$

that is,

$ab, cd \in R^\times.  \tag 5$

$OE\Delta$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $a,b\in R^\times $, exsist $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ in $R$.  Let $c = b^{-1}a^{-1}$, then $$(ab)\cdot c = a\underbrace {b\cdot b^{-1}}_{=e}a^{-1} = a \cdot a^{-1} = e$$

so $ab\in R^\times $.

Comment: didn't you proof that $(ab)c \in R^\times$ I don't see how this is a proof for $ab \in R^\times$

Comment: $(ab)c =e$ what does that say about $ab$? @Gykonik

Comment: ehm, that $(ab)=c^{-1}$?

Comment: So...............

Comment: $c^{-1}$ and $c$ has to be in $R^\times$?